# How to view blocking incoming requests on a Mac?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

When I program on my Mac laptop, sometimes it asks me if I want to accept incoming connections etc.

If I say no, I might want to change my decision later on.

Where can I see these firewall blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to System Preferences - Security - Firewall
- Unlock your settings if necessary using the lock symbol in the lower left.
- Click the "Advanced" button

Here you have a list of all rules set up:

[image]

You can then add rules for applications using the <kbd>+</kbd> button or remove some by selecting them in the list and clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> button.